# Css auto hide / show every 2s

Tags: html, css

I want to hide and show a div using css like :

Show => Hide => Show =>...

for do that I've tried that code:

```
#showMe {
  animation: cssAnimation 0s 2s forwards;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to   { visibility: visible;
        
  }
}
```

but it will hide it only plz guys help!!

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but please consider *why* you're doing this and whether there might be a better way to highlight what information you're trying to highlight. There's a reason browsers don't support the `<blink>` tag anymore.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by adding keyframes for a specific progress (time-progress).

Some attributes in CSS are not animateable, so if you try to animate them they get instantly set to your "to" value, which is `visible`. To work around this, we simply set the visibility to `hidden`(in css) and keep it until 50% (in animation). At 51% we set it to `visible`, where it gets instantly shown (until the end).

To make it "blinking" you can repeat this animation by appending `infinite` which is a shorthand for `animation-iteration-count: infinite`.

```css
#showMe {
  animation: cssAnimation 1s infinite;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  51% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="showMe">(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add property `animation-iteration-count` and set value it to `infinite`. It should play the animation infinite times.